# What do you call a short sung part sung by the second singer?

Tags: word-request

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3YxaaGgTQYM

Here's an example. The male singer sings a few phrases during the chorus. What are those sections or phrases called?

> [Wake me up] Wake me up inside
>
> [I can't wake up] Wake me up inside [Save me]
>
> Call my name and save me from the dark [Wake me up]
>
> Bid my blood to run [I can't wake up]
>
> Before I come undone [Save me]
>
> Save me from the nothing I've become

Comment: If it's repetitive, reprise. If it's copied, a beat or more from another, stretto. See https://www.successfulsinging.com/singing-guides/glossary-of-singing-terms/ for some others.

Comment: I think this is probably off-topic here, and would be better on music.stackexchange.com, because it's asking about a specific technical term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, this song is a duet, so the lines in brackets are the "backup vocals."

Comment: It may be stretching the term a bit, but you might also describe it as **counterpoint.**